# Call a function after Django model save/delete is called

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a lot of model classes in Django. NONE of them have an overridden save() or delete() function.

I want to create a Class level decorator which will be used to execute a function post save() / delete() is called. This class level decorator should be generic so that all the model classes can use it.

I have tried using the signals for post_save and post_delete, but maintaining a huge list of classes can be a problematic. I want to avoid overriding save()/delete() as well.

Any suggestions on how to go about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try creating an `abstract` model class and subclassing all your actual  models from that? By this way, when you attach `pre_save` signal to the base class, it is sent whenever any child model has been saved.

```
class SignaledModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(SignaledModel):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerNumber(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Course(SignaledModel):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

---

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=SignaledModel)
def model_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
    print('Saved an instance with type: {}'.format(sender))
```

Whenever a `Course` or `Student` instance is saved, `model_post_save` is called.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It solves the problem of maintaining the huge list of models. Just out of curiosity, is there any way we can accomplish it using the class level decorators?

Comment: I don't think so, as `save` method is an instance method *in other words, it works with "self"* thus, doesn't make sense implementing a class level decorator for this purpose.

Comment: I tried attaching the `pre_save` signal to the base class, but it did not work. Could you please include the code for the signal in your post? I have also tried a [different approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691004/django-signals-using-decorators-issue)

Comment: To which handler should I connect the `pre_save` signal in the base class?

Answer (score 1):

Using post_save signal is recommended.

If you don't want to register each model class individually, here is a solution with a class decorator:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class SaveRegister:
    registered_classes = []
    post_save_func = None

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, target_cls):
        if not cls.post_save_func:
            raise Exception("Post save function not defined")
        if target_cls not in cls.registered_classes:
            # prevent duplicate registration
            cls.registered_classes.append(target_cls)
            # register the model class to listen to post_save
            receive(post_save, sender = target_cls)(cls.post_save_func)

    # set the post_save signal handler
    @classmethod
    def set_post_save_func(cls, f):
        cls.post_save_func = f
```

Now all you have to do is define a post_save handler once, set it into the SaveRegister class:

```
def model_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
    print('Saved an instance with type: {}'.format(sender))
SaveRegister.set_post_save_func(model_post_save)
```

Every model class decorated with `SaveRegister.register` will automatically have a post_save handler:

```
@SaveRegister.register
class Student(SignaledModel):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerNumber(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

@SaveRegister.register
class Course(SignaledModel):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: Thanks Neo. I don't want to maintain a list of Models. So I am trying a different approach.