# django signals using decorators issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals, decorator

I have the below given structure in my project

```
-parentDirectory
 -myModule
   __init__.py
   models.py
 handler.py
```

models.py

```
@register
class Student():
    number = models.PositiveIntegerNumber(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

def post_delete:
    """some code"""

def post_save:
    """some code"""

@register
class Course(SomeBaseModel):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

`SomeBaseModel` has `post_delete` and `post_save` functions defined in it.

handler.py

```
def register(cls_object):
    @receiver(post_save, sender=cls_object.__name__)
    @receiver(post_delete, sender=cls_object.__name__)
    def _handler(sender, **kwargs):
        print 'inside _handler'

post_save.connect(_handler, sender=cls_object.__name__)
post_delete.connect(_handler, sender=cls_object.__name__)
return cls_object
```

The `_handler` is not getting executed when I delete any of the models. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `handler.py` being executed at any point?

Comment: its imported in `__init__.py`